# Pausing and Resuming a Thread in Android. Studio

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance, android-studio

I just want to create another thread, I need to have it to keep doing something until I click button A, then resume when I click on Button B, that's all.

```java
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

@Override

public void run(){ 

while(bool) { .... } 

}});

t.start();
```

This is the format that I'm trying to follow. I start at the onCreate, but **how do I pause and resume a thread?**

Answer (score 0):

Use `wait()` and `notifyAll()`.

Sample code for you to understand:

```
class myRunnable implements somethingRunnable {
    private Object mPauseLock;
    private boolean mPaused;
    private boolean mFinish;

    public myRunnable() {
        mPauseLock = new Object();
        mPaused = false;
        mFinish = false;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (!mFinish) {
            // Do stuff here.

            synchronized (mPauseLock) {
                while (mPaused) {
                    try {
                        mPauseLock.wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Call this on pause.
    */
    public void onPause() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = true;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Call this on resume.
    */
    public void onResume() {
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            mPaused = false;
            mPauseLock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use another flag to do this

example:

private boolean isPause = false;

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){

@Override

public void run(){

while(bool) {
 
  if(isPause){ Thread.sleep(500); continue; }

....

}

}});

t.start();

buttonA.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                  isPause = true;
             }
        });

buttonB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             Override
             public void onClick(View view) {
                  isPause = false;
             }
        });

Comment: I don't need to interrupt the thread? wouldn't keeping the thread running (even if it's not doing anything) consume processing?